# Why bootstraps glyphicons breaking the element?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, slim

I tried two different variants:

```
  td
    span.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-up 
    span &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Search
```

[image: span_not_bootstrap]

and

```
button#toggle_unimportant_search_params class=["btn", "btn-primary"]
  span.glyphicon.glyphicon-list
  span &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Show all parameters
```

[image: button_not_bootstrap]

vs

```
  td
    span.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-up Search
```

[image: span_bootstrap]

and

```
button#toggle_unimportant_search_params class=["btn", "btn-primary"]
  span.glyphicon.glyphicon-list Show all parameters
```

[image: button_bootstrap]

So it looks like the variants with additional `span &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` looks better. But this is not the bootstrap way as I know. The bootstrap way would be:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Star
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The right form using slim syntax for that elements would be:

```
td
  span.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-up 
  |  Search
```

and

```
button#toggle_unimportant_search_params class=["btn", "btn-primary"] type="button"
  span.glyphicon.glyphicon-list
  |  Show all parameters
```